# CSS + JQUERY Slider Errors

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I'm using that slider and I'm usually getting this error message in the Google Chrome Console. Is there a way to fix it?

Here's the [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLWNVO):

`slider.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null
slider.js:10 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of undefinedslider @ slider.js:10
slider.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null
slider.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of nullslider @ slider.js:10
slider.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of undefinedslider @ slider.js:10
slider.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of nullslider @ slider.js:10
slider.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for sure its better to include your code here  not just link to it .. but anyway

the problem is here `setInterval(function slider(){.....})`

just use `setInterval(function(){ ...... });`

you can take a look at this as well http://jsfiddle.net/uL50cqmw/ may be you need it later